# change status in cells after click on a button

Tags: excel

how I can change the No value in table 1 to YES base the person name in table 2 rows.

How can I build a function for this?

the sampling scheme of the sheet be like this :

[image]

Comment: This can be done in VBA.

Comment: I would add to @BigBen comment that this can be done **only** in VBA, as far as I know.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns - well maybe one could use Office-JS... either way, yeah it has to be done programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have your table going from column A to J using the image you've posted, so column A will hold the order number from the 1st table and column J will be the 'payback' of the 2nd table.

You can do this using just an IF function, combined with Index/Match. In column D ('payback' of Yes or No for the orders), input the following formula:

**=IF(INDEX($J$2:$J$4,MATCH($B2,$G$2:$G$4,0))="Yes","Yes","No")**

All you'll then actually need to do is to update column J, where you can input "Yes" or "No" and this will automatically update column D (the last column of your 1st table).

Then, you won't need VBA! Hope that helps :)

Comment: thanks for answering. two questions 
1. I can't use matches for an array of the name it must be one value so I get an error if set $J$2:$j$4 in the formula.
2.this function change column D base on the payback in tablee2  so if after someone payback and later have another transaction the value of D column by the Yes before even he payback actually